# What does E[XY]=0 mean?

Tags: econometrics, regression

Where X is a regressor and Y is the dependent variable.
I know that if E[XY]=E[X]E[Y] then X and Y are independent, hence uncorrelated but I don’t get what E[XY]=0 means.

Comment: A bit more context would help. Is $E[XY]=0$ an assumption or a result? The same goes for $E[Y]=0$.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ but not conversely.

Comment: Yes sorry, I made a mistake and it’s not E[Y]=0 but, again, E[XY]. 
Also, exactly, E[XY]=0 is an assumption.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a very fundamental confusion.
$E[XY]$ means that the result of $X*Y$ should average together to be 0.
Relevant operators are $E()$, which is *average*.

Implications can be very far reaching, but most notably is that (as mentioned above) if
$E[XY] \neq E[X]*E[Y]$ then $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. It is a good mental exercise to attempt to see if you can construct a minimal working example of variables that are independent or dependent.